# How to find all labels and graphs on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to migrate all graphs and labels of AgensGraph.

How to find all graphs and labels on AgensGraph?

Is there special table on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 1):

Use AG_GRAPH and AG_LABEL table for listing graphs and labels

```
agens=# SELECT GRAPHNAME, GRAPHID, LABID, LABNAME, LABKIND
agens-#   FROM AG_LABEL, PG_DEPEND, AG_GRAPH
agens-#  WHERE GRAPHID = REFOBJID AND OBJID = NSPID
agens-#  ORDER BY GRAPHID, LABID;
 graphname | graphid | labid |  labname  | labkind 
-----------+---------+-------+-----------+---------
 graph1    |   31830 |     1 | ag_vertex | v
 graph1    |   31830 |     2 | ag_edge   | e
 graph1    |   31830 |     3 | v         | v
 graph1    |   31830 |     4 | e         | e
 graph2    |   31863 |     1 | ag_vertex | v
 graph2    |   31863 |     2 | ag_edge   | e
 graph2    |   31863 |     5 | v         | v
 graph2    |   31863 |     6 | e         | e
 graph     |   39226 |     1 | ag_vertex | v
 graph     |   39226 |     2 | ag_edge   | e
 graph     |   39226 |     3 | v         | v
(11 rows)
```